# Mat Dialog AfterClose Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create dialog with form array when you save it and after closed all my
data will be in my main component my question is?
How to pass formarray in mat dialog afterclose and push it to my formarray.

```
this.deliveryReceiptForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id : [0],
      transactionStatus: ['DRAFT', Validators.required],
      transactionType : ['', ],
      serialArray: this.formBuilder.array([this.serialNum()])
    })

openDialogSerialLot(index: number){
  console.log(this.deliveryReceiptForm.value.displayArray);
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddSerialLotComponent, {
    data:{
    }
  })
  
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    // (this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('serialArray')as FormArray).at(index).patchValue(result)
      for (let i = 0; i < result.serialNum; i++) {
        this.serialArray.push(this.serialNum());
      }
      for (let i = 0; i <= result.serialNum; i++) {
        this.serialArray.at(i).patchValue({ qty: result.serialNum });
      }
    });
}
```

> MY MAT-DIALOG

```
this.serialForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      itemCode:['', Validators.required],
      qtyReceived:[0, Validators.required],
      displayArray: this.fb.array([this.CreateArray()]),
    });

get displayArray():FormArray{
    return this.serialForm.get('displayArray') as FormArray;
  }
  CreateArray():FormGroup{
    return new FormGroup({
      serialNum: new FormControl('', {validators: [Validators.required]}),
    });
  }

onSave(){
    this.http.post(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'users', this.serialForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    this.dialogRef.close(this.serialForm.value?.displayArray);
    console.log(this.dialogRef)
 }
```

Comment: What's the problem? You are sending in the close method of mat-dialog & then accessing it in afterClosed

Comment: @HassanMoin yes! like i want to send what i input in my mat dialog send it to my main component

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing? Display Array is being sent to your main.component afterClosed()

Comment: I can't pass it @HassanMoin

Comment: In your afterClose do console.log of the result. 
afterClosed().subscribe( response => console.log(response))

Comment: @HassanMoin the result is undefined

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to strongly type your matDialog return, like this :

```js
constructor(
    ...
    private matDialog: MatDialog,
    private matDialogAddSerialLotConfig: MatDialogConfig<matDialogAddSerialLotData>
  ) {
    ...
    this.matDialogAddSerialLotConfig = MatDialogConfigAddSerialLot;
  }

  openDialogSerialLot(index: number){
    console.log(this.deliveryReceiptForm.value.displayArray);
    this.matDialogAddSerialLotConfig.data = {};
    let dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(AddSerialLotComponent, this.matDialogAddSerialLotConfig)
    
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      // (this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('serialArray')as FormArray).at(index).patchValue(result)
        for (let i = 0; i < result.serialNum; i++) {
          this.serialArray.push(this.serialNum());
        }
        for (let i = 0; i <= result.serialNum; i++) {
          this.serialArray.at(i).patchValue({ qty: result.serialNum });
        }
      });
  }
```

```js
export const MatDialogConfigAddSerialLot: MatDialogConfig<MatDialogSerialLotData> =
  {
    id: 'serialLot-dialog-component',
    ...
  };

export interface MatDialogSerialLotData {
  SerialLot: SerialLot[];
}
```

So you will be able to debugg easier.